# Trying to flip the imageview on cell on gesture recognization, code is working fine but not getting flipped

Tags: ios, xcode, swift2, uicollectionview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a collection view, on collection view, I have taken `imageview`, I have added `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` on `imageview` which is working fine. It gets into the swiped method. In Swipe method, I am trying to flip the `imageview` which is on cell but it is not working.

Below is my code for clarification.

```
// collectionview delegate method in which I have added gesture.

    internal func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
    {
        let reuseIdentifier = "cell" // also enter this string as the cell identifier in the storyboard
        index = indexPath
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell
        let imageNameString = self.items.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! String

        let swipeLeft = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.swiped(_:))) // put : at the end of method name
        swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left
        cell.myImageView.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)

        cell.myImageView.userInteractionEnabled = true;
        cell.myImageView.image = UIImage(named: imageNameString)
        return cell;
    }

// Swiped Method called when we swipe on imageview

    func swiped(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {
        let reuseIdentifier = "cell" // also enter this string as the cell identifier in the storyboard

        let cell = self.myCollectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath:index ) as! MyCollectionViewCell


        if let swipeGesture = gesture as? UISwipeGestureRecognizer
        {
            switch swipeGesture.direction {

            case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left :
                print("User swiped left")
                cell.updateCell()
                self.myCollectionView.reloadData()
            default:
                break
            }
        }
    }
```

Update cell method is called when we swipe the `imageview` on cell but it does not flip. This code is working fine if I directly right it in `UICollectionViewCell`. I have taken custom class for `uicollectionviewcell`

```
func updateCell()
{
UIView.transitionWithView(self.contentView, duration: 0.6, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionFlipFromLeft, animations: {
            self.contentView.insertSubview(self.myImageView, aboveSubview: self.myImageView)
            self.myImageView.image = UIImage (named: "wallpaper2")      
            }, completion: nil)

    }
```

Any help would be appreciated. Where is the mistake?

Comment: Please enable the user interaction of the uiimageview  and try again

Comment: @Spynet I have already added cell.myImageView.userInteractionEnabled = true; Is there a need to add it again somewhere?

Comment: Once is enough i will check and update you mean while you also search ...

Comment: Ok. I am trying it again. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the solution -

//Replace the code  -

```
func swiped(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer)
 {
    let reuseIdentifier = "cell" // also enter this string as the cell identifier in the storyboard

    let cell = self.myCollectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath:index ) as! MyCollectionViewCell

    ....
   }
```

//With below code -

```
func swiped(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {

    let cell = self.myCollectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(index) as! MyCollectionViewCell
      .....
   }
```

I hope it helps, if someone is facing the same issue
Thanks to all above who tried to help to figure out the solution.

Answer (score 0):

After you perform the update of the image you are calling the collection view to reload again.

```
cell.updateCell()
self.myCollectionView.reloadData()
```

If you don't have a 'way' of knowing when a cell has being swiped before. The reloadData method will load the cells as it is the first time loading without any changed applied.

**Update**

But later when the cells redraws after scrolling up/down it should happen the same problem. I will suggest moving the image as property of your `UICollectionViewCell` custom class. Also to add a boolean inside that custom class that knows when your image has rotated. So any time you have to draw your cell you just call your draw method inside your custom class.

Comment: Ok. I will remove that line try it again

Comment: I tried it but at that time, when I added the gesture in custom class, the app was giving the fatal error. So I thought of doing it this way

Comment: I try removing the line as suggested, but facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

if you are using subclass of uicollectionviewcell, then assign gesture recogniser to your image view inside awakeFromNib. Also write swipe function to your custom class. So no need to dequeue again inside swipe

Comment: At start I added the gesture recognizer in uicollectionviewcell custom class, but it was getting crash - fatal error.

Comment: Ok. If you can try to do it again. Let me know what happens. Till then I also check once.

Comment: Ok. I am trying it again. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Could you provide how many UIViews do you have inside single collection view cell?

Comment: There is only one UIView I have found the solution. I will answer as solution to this question

Comment: Thats great. +1 for the answer. Happy coding